# Replace String path between production and development ENV using Browserify and Gulp

Tags: javascript, module, gulp, browserify

So my project is structured with a sources folder and inside that I have a classes folder and modules folder, inside the modules folder I have a file with import `import { Slider } from "../../classes/Slider";"` Outside the sources folder I have a dist folder where is my final destination files, with a folder called Controls where I get all my javascripts files, and outside Controls Folder I have a Bundle.js where I minify everything ready to production.
The problem is on development ENV everything works fine but when I run my command to bundle everything I need to replace the path on javascript file , because I have all Javascript files inside Controls folder, It's not anymore `../../classes/Slider";` but It suppose to be "Slider";" and on bundle It suppose to replace to  `../classes/Slider`.

Heres how It structured.

```
/dist
  /controls
    /slider.js
    /somemodule.js
  /bundle.js
/sources
  /classes
    /slider.js
  /modules
    /somemodule.html
    /somemodule.scss
    /somemodule.js
```

How can I do that with gulp and browserify?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gulp-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-env) to tell your gulp script which variable and environment is in use.

Another solution could be established with [minimist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist)

Both packages have docs with good examples, you can adapt those as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was install gulp-replace package,and then on my gulp file replace the string that I wanted